# Change logo on iTunes Connect before publish

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I created the app on iTunes connect I used the old logo for my app. Now I'm about to submit the first binary for validation and a new logo has been chosen. I cannot remove the app from iTunes Connect, since it will lock my app name and I cannot change the logo so the app will be rejected.

Can I contact Apple in any ways to help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you need to resubmit the app as far as i have seen.
Apple does not allow changes in icon as far as now unless you go for newer version of app.

Apart from that i would recommend you to go through the following link once:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2

Also i would suggest you to post same question on discussions.apple.com for more fruitful answers, as the question seems to be non-coding related.

Hope the link helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has relaxed some of the app information rules. You can update your meta information at any time in iTunesConnect. You should be able to update your iTunes artwork, description, and screenshots at any time. The icon that will display on the app is compiled into your code, so you will need to reject your binary or submit an update to get the correct icon to show on the device.